# Inaccurate License Count in Remote Desktop Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, remote-desktop-services, rds

Had an RDS License Server malfunction, opened a case w/ MS Tech Support, they were unable to fix.  Resolution was to delete license db, uninstall all RDS roles, reboot, reinstall, reboot, activate license server & re-install licenses, reboot.  Users are connecting fine, however...

RDS Server is in Per User Mode, 9 users connected currently.  License GUI shows 0 licenses in use. Refreshing, re-starting license service doesn't change count.  Running the license report for the domain (single domain, single RDS server) shows 4 user licenses in use.  MS support tech says "this is normal in per User mode, that only per device mode is accurate."

Does your 2008 R2 RDS License server provide accurate counts in Per User Mode?

Comment: If it works, and Microsoft says this is 'normal' why are you worried?

Comment: Because it's not working correctly, 9<>4. The question now is whether this is expected behavior.  A random tech will say a lot of things to close a case.